# How to use new node shapes in graphviz using python?

Tags: python, graphviz

I am creating some graphviz graphs using python. The default shapes (Shown in the picture) are not enough for me. I want to use more shapes. How can I do this with python? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use images containing whatever shape you may want to use:

```py
from graphviz import Digraph

dot = Digraph(comment='The Round Table')

#dot.node('A', label='King Arthur', shape='circle')
dot.node('A', label='King Arthur', color='transparent', image='/path/to/star.png')
dot.node('B', 'Sir Bedevere the Wise')
dot.node('L', 'Sir Lancelot the Brave')

dot.edges(['AB', 'AL'])
dot.edge('B', 'L', constraint='false')

dot.render('test-output/round-table.gv', view=True)
```

This creates the following:

[image]

I believe there are some limitations to how this approach can be used, as noted in [the documentation](https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqCustShape):

> *If using SVG (-Tsvg), PostScript (-Tps,-Tps2) or one of the raster formats (-Tgif, -Tpng, or -Tjpg), you can load certain images (e.g., pictures) by file name into nodes.*

Another approach is to use [HTML labels](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) which allow you to use `<IMG>` attributes.